# Funciona anónima auto ejecutable

Tags: javascript, jquery

Buenas tengo el siguiente código:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
        <p>Esto es un párrafo 1</p>
        <p>Esto es un párrafo 2</p>
        <p>Esto es un párrafo 3</p>
    <script>
        (function() { 
            $("p").css({"color": "blue", "background-color": "yellow"});
            });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Quiero saber ¿porque no se ejecuta automáticamente?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`(function(){})` retorna la referencia de la funcion por lo que tienes que ejecutarla como ejecutas una funcion, agregandole los parentesis `()`:

```
(function(){})();
```

Agrega los paréntesis para ejecutar la funciono y listo:

```js
(function() { 
    $("p").css({"color": "blue", "background-color": "yellow"});
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
        <p>Esto es un párrafo 1</p>
        <p>Esto es un párrafo 2</p>
        <p>Esto es un párrafo 3</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gracias! por ayudarme y responder :)